# Digital Ocean, Laravel and Mailgun

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, digital-ocean, mailgun

I'm running Laravel on Digital Ocean and trying to use Mailgun. Everything is configured correctly but when I try to run my script I get the error

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

on Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­vendor/­laravel/­framework/­src/­Illuminate/­Mail/­Transport/­MailgunTransport.php122

Has anybody encountered this issue?

Comment: Do you have guzzle in your composer dependencies?

Comment: I just ran php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~4.0 and it says Nothing to install or update. I also have a require "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0" in composer.json

Comment: Alright then, are you setting it up with `GuzzleHttp\Client` or `\GuzzleHttp\Client`? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22725266/899126) might be your problem