# How to Get Third party REST API data to LARAVEL.?

Tags: api, rest, laravel, oauth-2.0, restful-url

I am developing a laravel web application. I want to get third pary website ( **Mavenlink** ) --> **http://developer.mavenlink.com/** API Data. but i am new in api developing. how to get only the API of external site.

API URL : https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/

How to get the data with Laravel 4, once i googled, i can see a **OAuth2 tokens** . What is this ?

Please give me good solution for this, Now am stoped my project.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is using Guzzle. It will enable you to make all of the HTTP calls you need for an external API. See this article: [How to autoload Guzzle in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725266/how-to-autoload-guzzle-in-laravel-4)