# How to deploy an existing Laravel website in Localhost

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel website, hosted on server. Now I am trying to work on some of the modules, I am not getting how I can deploy it on my localhost.

These are the steps I have tried:

1. Downloaded the app folder from the Hosting server.
2. Installed a fresh Laravel 4 in my system .
3. Replaced the App folder with my website App folder.
4. Downloaded the databse and uploaded in my PHPMyadmin

But I am getting following error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>       Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found

The guy who developed the website he told he had used Laravel4 for that. 
When I tried to do `php artisan serve`
I got this error

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"include(C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\i
deconnect\\vendor\/intervention\/image\/src\/Intervention\/Image\/ImageServicePr
ovider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory","file":"C:\\Users
\\User\\Desktop\\ideconnect\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":378}}
```

**UPDATE**

When I did

`composer update`

I am getting following error

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"include(C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\i
deconnect\\vendor\/intervention\/image\/src\/Intervention\/Image\/ImageServicePr
ovider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory","file":"C:\\Users
\\User\\Desktop\\ideconnect\\vendor\\composer\\ClassLoader.php","line":378}}
```

Please guide me how to fix this problem.

Comment: You should give more details about your error: stack trace, file, line ecc.

Comment: @Moppo Updated my question

Comment: @Vikram : try to download all the folders and then change database connection.

Comment: Search for `moving laravel to host` and use that process while your brain is engaged. There are plenty of help/tutorials on the web

Comment: Search for `ImageServiceProvider` in your code - maybe it is in the wrong place, and the autoloader cannot find it? Is it in the `Application Service Providers` section of `config/app.php`?

Comment: Here your vendor folder does not have InterventionImage so you need to update via composer  try `composer update`

Comment: Since when is Symfony == Laravel4 ?

Comment: @KiranLM did that and updated my Question there is an error coming

Comment: @Pogrindis You see `Symfony` in a namespace and you assume it can't be Laravel? In fact Laravel uses a lot of Symfony packages.

Comment: @Bogdan indeed it does (was being facetious), so include them, what iwas getting at was they're not there by default.. Open your Laravel config file `config/app.php` and add the following lines.

In the `$providers array` add the service providers for this package.

`'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'`

Comment: @Pogrindis I checked its there :( , Already

Comment: verify there is `"intervention/image": "1.*"` on composer.json, if not, comment `'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'` and `'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'` from `config/app.php`

Comment: @KiranLM bro its working now but I could not see the images and css styles etc

Comment: That may because, you did not copied public folder that holds css and images

Comment: @KiranLM yes right I figured out , Now when I was creating a use its throwing  `'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found` Any leads on this ?

Comment: The solution may be here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725266/how-to-autoload-guzzle-in-laravel-4

Comment: @KiranLM I had commented the lines but now , some of the function related with image is not working It says image not found

Comment: class `Image` is in InterventionImage. You need to install it, `composer require intervention/image`  for more http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation